# pip: No module name _internal.main

Tags: python, pip, installation, package

In Windows, python 2.7, I had pip upgraded, and it showed:

```
Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.2
Successfully installed pip-19.3.1
```

But when:

```
pip --version
```

It shows:

[image]

I tried to 'reverse' to the old version by:

```
pip install pip==8.0.2
```

It shows the same error.

Not sure it's about the python version.

How can I correct this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right with trying to reinstall pip at an older verion; your installation is broken.

I've looked around and the consensus is that you should do:

`python -m pip install -U pip == 8.0.1`

then

`pip install -U pip`

There is a whole thread on Github on the pip repo that might be of help for you!
[Link to Github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5253)